# I'm very new to the spring security and OAuth2

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Hi I'm very new to Spring Security and OAUTH2 can any one help .... I'm using the example provided in this example http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html

What I'm trying to do is create 2 web applications where one app(mainApp) stores all the protected resources and does not know about the users and it needs to make a rest call to another app to get the details

Currently in my security config

```
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="abcd" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

In my case, I want to let our custom API which is in another app  do the authentication, then return a custom UserDetails object containing  the roles and other attributes

Comment: What's the problem? Please tell us as explicitly as possible what trouble you're having including any error messages you might be receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_sso_with_oauth2_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_v? I think the guide is quite interesting and offers a wide perspective of implementing OAuth2 and other security methods. Is there any reason because you need to use OAuth2? I mean, you can maybe start using Basic Authorization or token based approaches before to start with OAuth2 (which maybe is so complicated if you have no much experience).

Comment: I have a requirement for that I need to implement spring security.

Comment: Thanks for the example ...Actually I already gone through that I have to use xml config and not the java config